# any equivalent to VB.net function name as return value in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In vb.net there is a weird approach that you can use the function name as the result variable..

example:

```
Function Foo(ByVal bar As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Foo = New List(Of Integer)
    Foo.Add(bar + 1)
End Function
```

As far as i know, in C# you have to:

```
List<int> foo(int bar) 
{
     var result = new List<int>();
     result.Add(bar + 1);
     return result;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's by design or i just don't know the right way to do this..
Please enlight me!

Thanks in advance,
Eitan.

Comment: What is the question? You can use `Return` in VB.net

Comment: I'm asking about how to avoid declaring return variable on each  function in C#

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn’t support that. On a historical note, the only reason for VB to support this is that previous (pre-.NET) versions used the function name assignment *exclusively* – i.e. didn’t have a `Return` statement.<sup>1</sup>

There’s a general consensus among .NET developers that you should use the `Return …` method even in VB rather than using `FunctionName = …` and `Exit Function`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well actually they did but it did something else.

Comment: By previous versions, one means non .NET versions of Visual Basic (VB6 , VBScript and VBA).

Comment: @Oded LOL, in my mind “previous versions” is firmly VB6 even though we’ve long left VB7 behind us. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no C# equivalent. However, it is only sugar syntax in VB, as under the hood, the function name is replaced by `return` behavior anyway.

The readability of using function name as return param is highly debatable. Most don't like it.

`return` also offer an advantage that function name doesn't have, resolving the method at that specific place.

Comment: Yes, i did understood that.. but i'm trying to get my C# code sweeter (-:

Comment: @user1179861: If you want to make your C# sweeter, (or your VB) don't use function names. :)

Comment: @Oded: Code Dentists are always overpriced.

Comment: It's more than just syntactic sugar.  With a return statement, the method returns immediately.  When using the method name setter, it doesn't.  And you can thus change the value several times before it hits the end of the method, such as in a loop, or whatever.